# Export/Move sheets to new book

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with many sheets. I created many checkboxes on userform that if I want to create a copy of sheets, just check to that checkboxes and click to button1, the name of these copies like: "*(Excel)". How do I move those sheets "*(Excel)" to a new book?

```
'Create sheets
Dim Ctl As Control
For Each Ctl In Me.Controls
  If Ctl.Value = True Then Run Ctl.Tag
Next

'Move Sheets name *(Excel) to other workbook. But it's only move one sheet
Dim bReplace As Boolean, sh As Worksheet
Dim bk As Workbook
bReplace = True
For Each sh In Worksheets
If sh.Name Like "*(Excel)" Then
sh.Select Replace:=bDontReplace
bReplace = False
End If
Next
```

Besides, I want to export those sheets to PDF by another button.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach to move many sheets :

```
Sub CopyWorkbook()

Dim currentSheet as Worksheet
Dim sheetIndex as Integer
sheetIndex = 1

For Each currentSheet in Worksheets

    Windows("source workbook").Activate 
    currentSheet.Select
    if currentSheet.Name like "*(Excel)" then
       currentSheet.Move Before:=Workbooks("target workbook").Sheets(sheetIndex) 
    End if

    sheetIndex = sheetIndex + 1

Next currentSheet

End Sub
```

To export them as pdf this would do inside a button click event:

```
   SourceWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Select
   Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
      "C:\Users\you\Desktop\exported_sheet.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
      IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
      True
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: But I want to move many sheets with the same name such as in 6 sheets, I just move 3 sheets has same name at last _(Excel)_: "Data"; **"Grant (Excel)"**;"Asset"; **"Asset (Excel)"**; **"Bub (Excel)"**; "Final"

Comment: @kobebryant code i posted you moves all the sheets of the workbook no matter what name do they have.

Comment: dear jsanchezs, but I just want to move the sheets what I want, and those sheets have the same name at last "...(Excel)"

Comment: Oh i see, gimme a minute to update the answer @kobebryant

Comment: Done, check the updated answer and tell me how it goes @kobebryant

Comment: It's not run, and I want to move not copy jsanchezs

Comment: @kobebryant In that case just replace .Copy for .Move , i updated my answer so you can see